# give value to variable inside a function and access outside of it

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, express

i have simple form validation, what i am doing is: read json file, get property from it (Array) then check if it contains every single element of user generated array and nothing more, for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] (json file array)
[1,2,3,4,5,6] (U.G array) //it must return false
```

so i am using this code for implementing this:

```
 const contains = (arr1, arr2) => {
  arr2.every(v => arr1.indexOf(v) !== -1)
 }
   var match;
   fs.readFile('../tags.json', 'utf8', (err, data)=>{

     var JsonData = JSON.parse(data);
     var tagsArray = JsonData.tags;
     console.log(tagsArray)
     console.log(tags)
     if(tagsArray instanceof Array){
       console.log('tagsArray is array')
     }
      if(!contains(tagsArray, tags)){
        match = false
      }   
      else{
        match = true
      }
     console.log(match + ' blah1')

   });

   console.log(match + ' blah2')
 if(match == false){
    return res.status(409).send({
      message: 'Do not provide your own tags'
    });
  }
```

but it is returning false everytime because `contains(tagsArray, tags)` are undefined everytime. so what is the clue for this?

Comment: Try to debug with `console.log(data)` first. That is probably your first problem, not getting the correct data.

Comment: it is getting because when i log tagsArray , it gives me expected result

Comment: You are using [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) inappropriately. You should use Array methods instead.

Comment: I believe that contains checks to see if an item is an element of an array. You will need to iterate over your array.

Comment: oh my god, contains is not method, it is function i created

Answer (score 0):

The `match` variable inside your `fs.readFile` callback is the same variable `match` declared in the outer scope, thanks to closures.
Therefore, the problem is in the inner logic.

Answer (score -1):

see [fs.readFile document](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback): Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file.

so the execution order is:

[image: execution order]

or you can use `fs.readFileSync()`

Comment: moving second step into the block is causing errors